# glBindAttribLocation does not work like expected

Tags: opengl

I have a pretty basic OpenGL application with the vertices of a single triangle in a VAO. The vertex attributes are "p" for position and "c" for color. The shader is also very basic. It doesn't transform the positions and interpolates the colors of the 3 vertices over the triangle.

The problem occurs when accessing the attributes. If position is at location 0 and color at 1, the shader somehow swaps the attributes (interpreting color as position and vice versa). If the color is at 0 and position at 1, it works like expected.

I can't figure out, what is wrong and would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
...

GLint loc_p = 0, loc_c = 1; // works not
// GLint loc_p = 1, loc_c = 0; // works

glBindAttribLocation(shader1, loc_p, "p");
glBindAttribLocation(shader1, loc_c, "c");

glVertexAttribPointer(loc_p, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 8*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(loc_c, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 8*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(4*sizeof(GLfloat)));

do {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Render with shader 1
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glUseProgram(shader1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc_p);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc_c);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
} while(running);
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 430

in vec4 p;
in vec4 c;

out vec4 fCol;

void main() {
    fCol = c;
    gl_Position = p;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 430

in vec4 fCol;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = fCol;
}
```

Comment: Just as an aside, you can easily assign and attribute location inside your vertex shader with the appropriate `layout` qualifier. In your specific example you could write `layout (location = 0) in vec4 p;` and then simply use `0` instead of `loc_p`. The same goes for uniforms, btw. This saves various API calls. See [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) wiki page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to link the shader program using `glLinkProgram` after calling `glBindAttribLocation`. From the [OpenGL website](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml):

> Any attribute binding that occurs after the program object has been linked will not take effect until the next time the program object is linked.